# Javascript replace hypens with space

Tags: javascript

I am getting this value from DatePicker

```
var datepickr = 'Jun-29-2011';
```

I want to replace underscores(-) with space .

I tried this way , but it isn't working

```
var b = datepickr.replace("-",' ');
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Also, `-` is a hyphen, not an underscore. Take a look through Wikipedia's many articles on punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace` is supposed to take a regular expression:

```
var b = datepickr.replace(/-/g,' ');
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to research regular expressions to the full.

(The important bit here, though, is the flag `/g` — **global search**)

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference:

```
var datepickr = 'Jun-29-2011';
datepickr.replace("-",  " ");  // returns "Jun 29-2011"
datepickr.replace(/-/,  " ");  // returns "Jun 29-2011"
datepickr.replace(/-/g, " ");  // returns "Jun 29 2011" (yay!)
```

The difference is the global modifier `/g`, which causes replace to search for **all** instances. Note also that `-` must be escaped as `\-` when it could also be used to denote a range. For example, `/[a-z]/g` would match all lower-case letters, whereas `/[a\-z]/g` would match all a's, z's and dashes. In this case it's unambiguous, but it's worth noting.

**EDIT**

Just so you know, you can do it in one line *without* regex, it's just impressively unreadable:

```
while (str !== (str = str.replace("-", " "))) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var datepickr = 'Jun-29-2011';
var b = datepickr.replace( /-/g, ' ' );
```

The `/g` causes it to replace every `-`, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` works with regular expressions, like so:

```
> "Hello-World-Hi".replace(/-/g, " ")
Hello World Hi
```

Comment: Ok, now try with "Hello-Wor-ld" :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = 'Jun-29-2011'.replace(/-/g, ' ');
```

Or:

```
var b = 'Jun-29-2011'.split('-').join(' ');
```

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
var b = datepickr.toString().replace("-",' ');
```

I suspect that you are trying to replace chars inside a Date object.

Comment: `datepickr` is already a string. The definition's even in the question.

Comment: When fed with a string (or a regular expression without the /g modifier), `replace` only replaces the **first** instance it finds.

Comment: He said he is getting that value from Datepicker, it could also be a date.