# Javascript if string contains a space replace the space with a dash

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to write some code that will check if a previously defined variable has a space, and if it does, replace the space with a dash. This will be nested in another function.

```
function foo(){            
    // If stateName has a space replaces the space with a dash

    window.open('http://website.html/state-solar-policy/' + stateName);
}
```

Comment: [Here's the opposite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234073/javascript-replace-hypens-with-space), reverse the function args.

Comment: Why check? If there isn't a space to replace, nothing will happen, so you can forget the check. Just `str = str.replace(' ','-');`

Comment: @DanRedux. `" "` is only one white space option. `\s` capture them all.

Answer (score 9):

Use this regex:

```
stateName.replace(/\s/g,"-");
```

It will replace all white spaces chars with a dash (`-`)

**Note** that the regex will cause no troubles if the string doesn't have a space in it.
It replaces every white-space if finds with a dash, if it doesn't find, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "blah blah blah"
var new_string = string.replace(" ", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string="john doe is great";
var dashedstring=string.split(" ").join("-");
```

Comment: Why convert the string to array than convert it to string again? use regex.

Comment: Old habits die hard. I still use this cause this is all I had in the 90’s. for larger than 300 words strings I start looking for something more efficient.

Comment: I’mpretty sure there was. windows 95 has javascript. Thats when I started learning.

Comment: I don't think the quality measure is the time posted, but as you wish sir!